# Making an efficient search engine for my website

Tags: php, database-design, search-engine

My database contains tens of millions of products, so I need an efficient search technique to speed up my response. Initially, I tried making a number of tables based on alphabets or some initial characters of the query. However, that fails many times, e.g. if the user searches for "ipod touch" instead of "apple ipod touch." Can I implement this using a trie or some other data structure? How does Google keep track of so much data?

Comment: Current slow status of my website can be seen here http://compare.buyhatke.com

Comment: Nice site. How do you get this content? Are you using an API or scraping the content from the sites?

Comment: Good voters on SO do not -1 when you "ask something big." Good voters -1 low quality questions that show no effort or are unclear.

Comment: @JoyceBabu Thanks !! Currently we are scraping the website. But in the next launch, we are thinking of making it more of a database kind of thing, with efficient crawling. That will not only speed up the results , but also improve UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a full text search. You could try using the `FULLTEXT` index in MySQL and perform a `MATCH AGAINST` query.

But I think you will have much better luck with Apache Solr. It is fast, scalable and provides much better (relevant) results.

Comment: I am not at all aware about this Apache Solr. Can you just tell me in a line or two, can it be integrated between mysql database and PHP. And also , do mention , if you have some suggestions for the website

Comment: Solr is a separate search index. You will have to update it separately. There is a dataimport handler for MySQL, which allows you to import data directly from your database.

Answer (score 5):

Making your own search algorithm is difficult. When I had to do something similar for a project, I simply trawled the entire database, column by column, searching for all, then any terms; it was crude, but it worked since the database would never realistically hold more than ten thousand entries. Given the size of your database, you're much better off looking into some pre-made search engines: those things are really well written and optimized. As Joyce Babu suggested, Apache Solr is one; another suggestion I'd like to make is [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). It is (according to Wikipedia) used on craigslist where it serves 200 million searches a day; that sort of power should be more than enough to handle what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I would go through them and post in case of any doubt